# How can I check the version of cplex installed on my python?

Tags: python, cplex

i'm using the cplex on python. I'm trying to solve a MIP with roughly 280000 variables.
However,  error, "Exception has occurred: CplexSolverError
CPLEX Error  1016: Community Edition. Problem size limits exceeded. Purchase at [http://ibm.biz/error101"](http://ibm.biz/error101%22), appeared. //
To solve this, I want to make sure that IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio is installed correctly, not community version. How to check this?
The license i have is IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.10.0

Answer (score 2):

if you run

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve(log_output=True,)
```

from the [zoo example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/) you ll see the cplex version

Example:

```
Version identifier: 12.10.0.0 | 2019-11-26 | 843d4de2ae
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem with your answer